# Linking Error Using HsLua on Windows

Tags: haskell, lua, mingw, ld, ffi

I am having some issues using HsLua as a library.  Lua compiles just fine as a standalone.  And this version runs on my Linux box without a problem.  Here is the linking error I see.

```
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import Scripting.Lua as Lua
Prelude Lua> l <- Lua.newstate
Loading package hslua-0.3.4 ... linking ... <interactive>: C:\..\AppData\Roaming\cabal\hslua-0.3.4\ghc-7.4.1\HShslua-0.3.4.o: unknown symbol `___strtod'
ghc.exe: unable to load package `hslua-0.3.4'
Prelude Lua>
```

I did some poking around the libraries and found the call for strtod and I think I may have been close but obviously not close enough.

**EDIT**

This may or may not help.  I'll post the cabal file, I made a couple of changes such as adding the os(windows) portion.

```
Name: hslua
Version: 0.3.4
...
Extra-source-files: src/*.h

Library
  Build-depends: base==4.*
  Exposed-modules: Scripting.Lua, Scripting.Lua.ConfigFile
  Hs-source-dirs: src
  C-sources: src/lapi.c, src/lauxlib.c, src/lbaselib.c, src/lcode.c,
             src/ldblib.c, src/ldebug.c, src/ldo.c, src/ldump.c, src/lfunc.c,
             src/lgc.c, src/linit.c, src/liolib.c, src/llex.c, src/lmathlib.c,
             src/lmem.c, src/loadlib.c, src/lobject.c, src/lopcodes.c,
             src/loslib.c, src/lparser.c, src/lstate.c, src/lstring.c,
             src/lstrlib.c, src/ltable.c, src/ltablib.c, src/ltm.c,
             src/lundump.c, src/lvm.c, src/lzio.c, src/ntrljmp.c
  Include-dirs: src
  ghc-options: -Wall
  extensions: ForeignFunctionInterface


  if os(linux)
    CC-Options: "-DLUA_USE_LINUX"

  if os(darwin)
    CC-Options: "-DLUA_USE_MACOSX"

  if os(freebsd)
    CC-Options: "-DLUA_USE_POSIX"

  if os(windows)
    CC-Options: "-DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL"
    includes: stdlib.h
```

I tried a couple of different ways to get the stdlib in the project, I've added it in main headers for the project and I've also specified it in the cabal file.  Makes me think that is barking up the wrong tree.

**EDIT-2**

Well I haven't been able to get this built yet on win32.  A couple of other things I tried to do that didn't work for me just in case someone else runs into the same problem.

I linked all of the built object files into a static archive and I got the same error as above.  I also tried to use a build DLL and I got a different error but I'm not sure if it were progress forwards or backwards.

```
C:\..\hslua-0.3.4>ghci liblua.dll -package hslua
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package hslua-0.3.4 ... linking ... ghc.exe: C:\..\hslua-0.3.4\ghc-7.4.1\HShslua-0.3.4.o: unknown symbol `_lua_close'
ghc.exe: unable to load package `hslua-0.3.4'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I was struggling with exactly the same thing on windows and what worked for me was adding the following to the cabal file

```
  if os(windows)
     CC-options:        "-D__NO_ISOCEXT"
```

that makes gcc not use the special __strtod but rather just the normal one.

Comment: What does your environment look like? I definitely don't have the same error as before, but I do have an unknown symbol error in ntrljmp.o.  Are you linking against a static or shared library?